# For some reason, $_SESSION is not working in Android application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, session

I am trying to store the logged in user in a new session, get the info from the database, put it to a json array, then get the array in android and display the results in a layout. When I run the app however, the array being returned from the php file is empty. If I am to test the php file however in a different program such as Postman, I get the correct response

```
{"result":[{"id":"12","fname":"C","lname":"Wei","username":"cw","email":"werrs.‌​com"}]}
```

Here is the php file and java method.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = '$username'";

    require_once('connect.inc.php');

    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
        array_push($result, array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'fname' => $row['fname'],
            'lname' => $row['lname'],
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

In Postman, it successfully gets the logged in user, however in android it does not.

```
    private void getUserData() { StringRequest stringRequest = new 
    StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,              
            Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        //json string to jsonobject
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        //get json sstring created in php and store to JSON Array
                        result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.json_array);

                        //get username from json array
                        getUserInfo(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getUserInfo(JSONArray jsonArray){
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            userInfo.add(json.getString(Config.getUsername));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve a previously initiated session on server side, your request must contain the session id (of that previous session) as a GET parameter.

Default for PHP ist PHPSESSID=XXXX.

Cookies are the reason why it does not fail in Postman. PHP automatically attaches a header for a cookie with the corresponding session ID.

Comment: Do i do this using a hashmap?

Comment: Just store the previously obtained session id in a format which suits best your needs and attach it to following requests: Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php?PHPSESSID=" + myPreviouslyStoredSessionId

Comment: Im stuck:/ Thanks for the help anyway though

Comment: I cant figure out how to get the session id and store it in a variable in the java file. I saw that I can use seesion_id() to get the id but I cant seem to be able to store it anywhere.

Comment: You can send it in php via header: header('X-Session-Id: ' . session_id()) or echo it via json: json_encode(['sessionId' => session_id()]). In your android app just store the session Id and use it in the following requests.

Comment: Okay, I have a method that returns a string of getSessionId() that calls my getsessionId.php. `<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
  session_start();
  $sessionid = session_id();
  echo json_encode(['sessionId' => $sessionid]);
 }
 
?> `  now my method is getting a null stringRequest, is this the same problem I was originally having?

Comment: I was able to finally get the session ID from the login php file. I am storing it in shared preferences then calling it during my stringrequest. However I am now getting an unexpected response code 500. Here is how I am calling it:

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String sessionId = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.SID, "SessionID");

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php?PHPSESSID=" + sessionId,